# How to combine two or more neo4j cypher result columns

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Can I combine multiple neo4j cypher result columns into one array? The use case is I  have a query that return an array of multiple columns:

```
......
RETURN a AS post, b AS author, c AS comment
```

Cypher returns this as three distinct sets of arrays a,b and c. Though these are connected data I only have a column view of each. I can use

```
result.records[i].get('post') 
result.records[i].get('author') 
result.records[i].get('comment')
```

but I can't assume that 'author' in [i] is the author of post[i]. So I need to have a RETURN where a, b and c is in row[i]..which means collapsing all three columns into one. So I want my resultArray to look like this:

```
 resultArray: [{a,b,c},{a,b,c},....]
```

where result.records[0] = {a,b,c}.

I hope I was able to explain the use case, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple fields as follows:

```
RETURN {post: a, author: b, comment: c}
```